# iOS - create UIButton manually with given size

Tags: ios, uiview

I’ a little confused with UIView’s bounds and frame. I’m creating UIButton manually with the same size as its super view:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:aView.bounds]; 
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; 
[aView addSubview:button];
```

But in the simulator the button and its super view have different size. I don’t really understand this..

(I didn't use IB to create the button because next I’d like to create a 2D array of buttons within that super view, so I think maybe it’s better to create them manually)

Comment: Where are you putting this code?

Comment: In the `viewDidLoad`. You are right I should move it to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suspect you're putting you code in `viewDidLoad` before the view has has a chance to finish laying out its subviews. Move your code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to use aView.frame rather than aView.bounds.  Both will give you the size (width and height of the aView) but frame gives you the position of aView in its superview.  The button will need the position relative to aView not aView's superview. Bounds will give you aView's position in its own coordinate system (most likely 0, 0).

What could be happening is you are creating the button using aViews size before aView's frame has been determined.  When is aView's frame being determined? Is aView being created via interface builder?  When are you creating the button?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided does work - that is the correct way to make a subview the same size as its superview. There are two possible explanations for why you think that isn't happening:

- You might be misinterpreting what you see in the simulator. The view you see behind the button might not be `aView`. I'm going to discount that possibility and go with the second possibility:
- You are running that code before `aView` achieves its final size. In other words, you are inserting `button`, but then layout comes along and changes the size of `aView`. That change in the size of `aView` doesn't change the size of `button`, so `button` is left with the size `aView` *used* to have at the time you created and inserted it.